# View new posts in Google+ Trending Topics

Tags: google-plus

Is there a way to only see new posts of a Google Plus trending topic, such as the [#TreeTuesday](https://plus.google.com/s/%23TreeTuesday/posts) theme? I only want to see the ones posted on that day and not ones from months in the past.

Answer (score 4):

At the top of the stream are two links

- Best of
- Most recent

[image: Google Plus search screen shot]

The latter, obviously, is what you want.

The Pause button allows you to pause the stream, of course, so you can enjoy the photo you're looking at before it scrolls off the bottom of your screen.